# Create simulink block using existing m files

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to create simulink block with existing matlab files. i have system with signal processing technique. I use simulink block "Matlab Function".

In that function i define,

```
 x = audioread('test\test2.wav');
```

but it gives an error,
[image]

how can i solve this?

Comment: Please insert the error message in a way it is readable.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to solve this, either use the [read from media file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/frommultimediafile.html) block to have a simulink only solution or use `coder.extrinsic`.

Comment: when i use  x = audioread('test\test2.wav'); it gives 46552 * 1 matrix. but when i use above simulink block it gives 217*1 matrix. i want to get frequency against time as a matrix. will this block solve this? @ Daniel

Comment: Per default (sample time from file) the block outputs the samples one by one. If you instead enforce a slower sample time it will output larger pieces of the audio file, each as long as your sample time.

Comment: [x , fs]= audioread('test\test2.wav'); it gives fs=22050. will i need to give this value in "Samples per audio channel" field? @  Daniel

Comment: If you really want to process the full file in one sample step, yes. That's typically not the way digital signal processing is done.

Comment: Are there  From wav file, To wav file blocks available in R2014a?

Comment: You will find the "to media file"  block in the "see also"  section of the documentation I linked.

Comment: i check inherit sample time from file and i use  Samples per audio channel as 22050. it gives 11*1 matrix. i couldn't solve this problem. i'm new to simulink library. help me. @  Daniel thankyou

Comment: @ Daniel i tried with coder.extrinsic. it gives "Subscripting into an mxArray is not supported." error. should i need to use coder.extrinsic to each function, matlab commands? pls help me

Comment: When i use this with  Interpreted MATLAB Function bock it gives "called with incorrect number of arguments"

Comment: @BirunthaG: I can not further help you with your problem, because I do not fully understand it. I recommend to improve your question. As I already mentioned, please insert the error message in a way it is readable. Probably most of the readers skipped your question because they where unable to read it. Further, give a short explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @  Daniel  i create one Interpreted MATLAB Function block in that i call matlab file it contains code as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591501/create-interpreted-matlab-function-block-in-simulink
it gives lot of errors. i tried to solve this by read from media file and coder.extrinsic. but still gives errors.